# how to convert Python 3 to Python 2 code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had written a program in Python 3, but now want to convert it into Python 2 code. Are there any utilities to do that automatically?

Comment: When you have this problem, it may be a sign you're doing it backwards.  Python 2to3 is built-in.  Why didn't you start in Python 2 and use the built-in 2to3 tool?

Comment: @S.Lott: "If your project is brand-new or does not have a large codebase, then you may want to consider writing/porting all of your code for Python 3 and use 3to2 to port your code for Python 2." - a valid strategy described in http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/pyporting.html

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You want [`3to2`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/3to2) for that.