# How would I combine multiple .py files into one .exe with Py2Exe

Tags: python, pyqt, py2exe

I used PyQt to make a GUI for my program, but it has multiple .py files, 2 are them are classes, and one launches the code. So I was wondering, how would I combine them into one whole program?

Here is a download link to all the .py files I will be combining: http://www.multiupload.com/CJDL639CTH

Comment: Have you actually tried using py2xe yet? All you need is a proper setup.py file with the appropriate py2exe hook to your app's entry point. Py2exe should take care of the rest unless you have some funky packaging and/or dependancies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shed Skin](http://shed-skin.blogspot.com/) can turn your program into a fast executable, but maybe that doesn't work for your program.

With [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) and [a setup.py like this](http://ideone.com/bGA5O) you can easily turn your Python 2.x code in Windows into an executable with only one extra file, unlike [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)'s flat output of 11 files. **For Python 3, use cx_Freeze, or [py2exe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe).**

The key part is:

```py
    options={
            'py2exe': {
                    'compressed': 2,
                    'optimize': 2,
                    'includes': includes,
                    'excludes': excludes,
                    'packages': packages,
                    'dll_excludes': dll_excludes,
                    'bundle_files': 1,  # 1 = .exe; 2 = .zip; 3 = separate
                    'dist_dir': 'dist',  # Put .exe in dist/
                    'xref': False,
                    'skip_archive': False,
                    'ascii': False,
                    'custom_boot_script': '',
                    #'unbuffered': True,  # Immediately flush output.
            }
    },
    zipfile=None,  # Put libs into .exe to save space.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am using Python 3.2 and I am not familiar enough with Python 2.x to convert my code to it. Besides that, it would work flawlessly.

Comment: @user976299 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533217/how-to-convert-python-3-to-python-2-code

Comment: Please comment as to the reason of downvoting. Both cx_Freeze and py2exe appear to work with Python 3.3 code.

Comment: 'a setup.py like this' link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Use [squeeze](http://effbot.org/zone/squeeze.htm) than [ExeMaker Tool](http://effbot.org/zone/exemaker.htm). May be able to use Py2Exe after squeeze. Have never used Py2Exe.