# RuntimeError when using py2exe to convert program and passing options

Tags: python, exe, py2exe, distutils

I'm attempting to convert a python program into an executable using py2exe, following the [tutorial flow](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial). I've created a setup.py as below (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950335/how-would-i-combine-multiple-py-files-into-one-exe-with-py2exe) example).

```py
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe

    options = {
        'py2exe': {
            'compressed': 1,
            'optimize': 2,
            'bundle_files': 3, #Options 1 & 2 do not work on a 64bit system
            'dist_dir': 'dist',  # Put .exe in dist/
            'xref': False,
            'skip_archive': False,
            'ascii': False}}

    setup(options=options, zipfile=None, console=['main.py'])
```

When I run `python setup.py py2exe` in Anaconda command prompt (set up to run a python 3.5 environment), I get the following error trace:

```
    running py2exe
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 14, in <module>
        }, zipfile=None, console=['main.py'])
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 188, in run
        self._run()
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 267, in _run
        builder.analyze()
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 173, in analyze
        target.analyze(mf)
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 74, in analyze
        modulefinder.run_script(self.script)
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 86, in run_script
        self._scan_code(mod.__code__, mod)
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
        self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 394, in _scan_code
        self.safe_import_hook(name, mod, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_hook
        self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
        module = self._gcd_import(name)
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
        return self._find_and_load(name)
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 356, in _find_and_load
        if module.__code__:
      File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35_env\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 637, in __code__
        raise RuntimeError("should read __file__ to get the source???")
    RuntimeError: should read __file__ to get the source???
```

I tried following the traceback, but wasn't able to figure out the root of the error. Any suggestions on what my issue is and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears my error was related to a lack of support in py2exe for python 3.5. I ran into a similar (though not identical error) when I ran the tutorial example (hello world) listed in the tutorial linked in my question, which is how I identified the issue.

I created a new Anaconda environment with a python 3.4 interpreter, and was able to build an executable for my original application successfully.