# How to package multiple Python files into an .exe

Tags: python, package, pyinstaller

I am a total noob when it comes to this, but I have been tasked to package several Python files into one .exe file.

I tried doing this with PyInstaller and I realized that I wasn't able to import opencv at first. Sure enough, I pasted a copy of cv2.pyd into the site packages folder and that was corrected. I tried building it again but it still doesn't work.

The command I use is: `pyinstaller --onedir C:\Users\ -- Directory of Python file` The file I'm using is the main one, that makes the program run. I thought PyInstaller would have scanned this file and find the other imported files.

**I'm not sure how to add the other files**. The documentation on the PyInstaller website isn't super clear to me.

More Info: Application consists of a GUI with 5 Python files in total
Application packages but doesn't run (Command Window blips and goes away)

Any suggestions?
Thanks a million - Matt

Comment: This link should be helpful for both Python 2 and Python 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950335/how-would-i-combine-multiple-py-files-into-one-exe-with-py2exe

Comment: Thank you for the link. I managed to figure it out. Turns out that I needed to install PyInstaller in my Anaconda folder and not the regular python folder. After that, Everything else checked out fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I combine multiple .py files into one .exe with Py2Exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950335/how-would-i-combine-multiple-py-files-into-one-exe-with-py2exe)