# How to compile different python files into one exe in python 3.6?

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze, python-3.6, pyke

[picture of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ySpw.png)

I am using python3.6 and i successfully compile single python file into single exe using cx_freeze but now i wish to compile different files(shown at the picture above) into one exe file. May i know is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use py2exe. It works for you in the way you wanted. Also check this topic: [How would I combine multiple .py files into one .exe with Py2Exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950335/how-would-i-combine-multiple-py-files-into-one-exe-with-py2exe)

Comment: py2exe support python3.6?

Comment: py2exe is outdated for python 3.6

Comment: py2exe has had python3 support for a few years now: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-announce-list/2014-May/010295.html

Comment: i am currently using python3.6 and py2exe does not support python 3.6