# _tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, cx-freeze, python-3.6

I tried all the previous available solutions available on Stackoverflow but nothing seems to work at all.
I am using **64-bit python** and **python 3.6.1** by Anaconda.

Here is what I receive as an error while I run my exe:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Asgard\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\Asgard\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "fbroi.py", line 80, in <module>
    root = Tk(className=" ROI Calculator")
  File "C:\Users\Asgard\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2017, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories:
    {C:\Users\Asgard\Desktop\ML Proj\EdCrawler\build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\tk} {C:/Users/Asgard/Desktop/ML Proj/EdCrawler/build/exe.win-amd64-3.6/tcl/tk8.6} {C:/Users/Asgard/Desktop/ML Proj/EdCrawler/build/exe.win-amd64-3.6/tk8.6} {C:/Users/Asgard/Desktop/ML Proj/EdCrawler/build/lib/tk8.6} {C:/Users/Asgard/Desktop/ML Proj/EdCrawler/lib/tk8.6} {C:/Users/Asgard/Desktop/ML Proj/EdCrawler/build/library}
```

Copying tcl8.6 and tk8.6 directories here and there, don't seem to work also.

Comment: can you share the setup file you use with cx-freeze?

Comment: Sure.
[link](http://ideone.com/AkldZ4)

Comment: in your `build_exe_options` try adding `tkinter` to your packages list. you are including the DLLs, but there are many "supporting" files that are also needed, including the package should fix that

Comment: Nope. Did not work. Got the same error again.

Comment: in your build folder, you should have a `tk` and a `tcl` folder, can you check if you have a `tk.tcl` in the `tk folder? how many files/folders are present in each of these folders?

Comment: Yes I have a tk and tcl folder. But tk.tcl is missing from tk folder. Each folder has 5 sub directories and 10 files under it.

Comment: @JamesKent Are you still looking into it? I tried a lot of other things but nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
It seems that there is no possible solution for me. I had to get rid of `cx_Freeze`.

What works for me is this:

1. Downgrade your python to **3.3** or less because **py2exe** does not support python **3.6**. If you're using **conda** create a **virtual environment**. It easily allows installing any python version you want.
2. Get **py2exe** on your python environment.
3. Use `py2exe`.

You might find this useful : [py2exe usage on Stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950335/how-would-i-combine-multiple-py-files-into-one-exe-with-py2exe)

For people using conda : [python and conda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html)