# Python-2to3: Safe Set of Fixers for Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-2to3

What subset of Python 2to3 fixers output valid Python 2 code?

Rather than move to Python 3 all at once, I'd like to use 2to3 to get most of the way there, saving the really hairy stuff (e.g., unicode changes) for a later time or possibly using `six` to support both. I'd like an initial pass to be done by `2to3`, but I want it to generate valid Python 2 code as an intermediate step.

Note: I'm aware of [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223761/which-2to3-fixers-output-valid-python-2-code), but it wasn't really answered.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found a tool `futurize` that does this for you. In EPEL there's even an RPM for CentOS 6 (which I am stuck with on some machines at work) - it's `python-future`.

http://python-future.org/automatic_conversion.html - stage 1 is the "prep for python 3 while maintaining compatibility" with stock packages. I've found that stage 2 requires other packages that are installed with it, but not available on other machines when I copy the scripts around.

One example:
`futurize -l -f all -f idioms -f ws_comma -x long *py`

Adding `-w` will write the changes back out for you.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you're going to find one. Your best approach instead is to use the #! syntax to indicate what Python you want to use and use 2to3 as you're ready on each one. (If you're on Windows, look into [Python launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) to make coexistence a little easier.)

I have one module I wrote that needs to work with both 2 and 3; and I have code at the top that looks like this:

```
import sys
PYTHON3 = sys.version_info.major == 3
PYTHON2 = sys.version_info.major == 2

if PYTHON2:
    import StringIO
    stringio = StringIO.StringIO
    bytesio = StringIO.StringIO # In Python2, stringIO takes strings of binary data
    import urllib2
    URL_open = urllib2.urlopen
    HTTPError = urllib2.HTTPError

if PYTHON3:
    import io
    stringio = io.StringIO
    bytesio  = io.BytesIO # In Python3, use BytesIO for binary data
    import urllib.request
    URL_open = urllib.request.urlopen
    import urllib.error
    HTTPError = urllib.error.HTTPError
```

and scattered throughout things like:

```
if PYTHON2:
    f = stringio(self.XMLData)
if PYTHON3:
    f = bytesio(self.XMLData.encode(encoding="utf-8"))
```

It's not like there's way of expressing a line that will work in both systems. You need a lot of patching like this. It's really not worth it unless you have a use case (like this) where there's some reason you must support both Python2 and Python3 in one module.

My use case was *relatively* straightforward. The [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223761/which-2to3-fixers-output-valid-python-2-code) you refer to points to the Dive Into Python ["Porting Code to Python 3 with 2to3" chapter](http://diveintopython3.problemsolving.io/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html), which shows how much stuff is different, much of which is *incompatibly* different, requiring a lot of conditional coding as above. I wouldn't recommend it.